# Adding window.resize event in vuejs component is not working independently

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a image slide component which has resize event

**imageSliderComponent.vue**

```
methods: {
 resize: function () {
   console.log(this.$el)
   // Handle window resize
   // Code
 }
}
mounted () {
 window.onresize = this.resize
}
```

And in the parent component i am using this image slider in multiple places, some thing like this

**App.vue**

```
<image-slider :data="data1" />   // Slider 1
<image-slider :data="data2" />   // Slider 2
```

So when i try to resize the window, window.resize event is working only for the last occurred component(i.e., Slider 2). For the first component(Slider 1) resize method is not working.

Is there any way to handle resize independently for reusable component? please suggest if there is any other different implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overriding the `onresize` handler every time, this causes only the last mounted component to work.

You need to instead use `addEventListener`:

```
mounted () {
 // You probably also want to call .bind as otherwise the `this` will not point to the component
 this._boundedResize = this.resize.bind(this); // Store in a var in order to remove it later
 window.addEventListener("resize", this._boundedResize);
}

destroyed() {
 window.removeEventListener("resize", this._boundedResize);
}
```